nonsensical downvotes and what to do about them
This post and the three answers each receiving a downvote prompts me to write this and ask our moderators to do something about the problem.
I usually upvote answers receiving nonsensical downvotes as these three have, but this time I am not doing so; these answers do not deserve to be downvoted, and I want the moderators to notice this. If there ever was an excellent example of proving that downvotes should always be accompanied by at least a single sentence of reasoning in the comment section, even if given anonymously, then these three answers each with a downvote proves my point.
If you do not like my suggestion, then, please, do something else but do something. Thank you.

At the time of this comment, the downvote on the question has been retracted.

Votes and their timing can always be observed. Up voting won't obscure anything if the issue is raised

What are you proposing that the moderators do? We don't have access to identifiable votes, and we can't compel people to write comments.

@rob I suggest that the only way one should be able to downvote is to write a short explanation in the comment line for the reason; this will help both the one who posted the question and the one who answered it but has now got the downvote. This would require a change in the code. If the required comment was obvious nonsense then it will be obvious to everybody reading it that it could be ignored. I would not even mind if the comment connected to the downvote is written under a global "anonymous" name; I am only asking that a single line of explanation for the downvote be attached.

@rob while I was writing my answer to you, my question got a downvote from which I learned nothing, but neither has anybody else learned anything from this downvote. Why is this good for anybody? If my question is idiotic but it is worth the trouble to downvote it, then it would be even more worthwhile to explain why it is so idiotic. I understand that the moderators cannot do anything now, it would have to be a new feature, but I am proposing that it be added to the next (?) SE code update and I think I would have to convince the moderators and get their help for that to happen.

@hyportnex This issue (of requiring comments for downvotes) has been discussed many times. Just use the search function and you will find many previous posts on the same issue. The problem is that moderators can't do much as they do not have the ability to view and modify votes. Only SE staff have such abilities.

@hyportnex However I do agree though that basics' (detailed and clear) answers are often downvoted for no justifiable reason. If they suspect targeted downvoting they can raise the issue to staff.

"while I was writing my answer to you, my question got a downvote from which I learned nothing, but neither has anybody else learned anything from this downvote." Down votes on a meta question like this mean "no, I don't want this to be a thing" They aren't against you or something to learn from.

Actually, the real problem is that we have users who give "revenge upvotes" to counter-act downvotes because they like a user. Perhaps instead of seeing the -1 and immediately reacting to give a +1, you could read the post and determine what someone could possibly have DV'd about it (for instance, is it a complete non sequitur? is there something erroneous or misleading? is it too high or too low level for OP?).

@KyleKanos I fully agree. Some users go around upvoting every single negatively-scored question, even completely egregious ones.

Another example of recent nonsense downvotes on this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/546763/regarding-the-objects-in-free-fall-in-the-iss and all of its (historical) answers. I have upvoted them again.

I really don't understand using upvotes to "reverse" downvotes. If it brings the post to your attention and you actually think it deserves an up vote, then awesome. But just seeing "oh, everything is being downvoted; let me be a hero" without actually assessing the content to see if it deserves the up vote just makes you just as bad as serial down voters IMO.

@BioPhysicist you are making an assumption that I neither implied nor would I approve of. Speaking of what can or cannot be understood: I do not understand the hostility to my suggestion; to me this is an issue of utility (80%) and civility (20%). The former is 4 to 1 more important to me than the latter. I was taught and brought up to stand by openly what I say. I would not criticize anybody or anything without giving a reason, this is both for the utility implied by the criticism and as a matter of civility to standi by that claimed  civility. Indeed, I am a geezer.

@BioPhysicist As this forum and most of internet is mostly anonymous the lack of civility is one result of such anonymity. Granted, I am as well as almost everybody here has a user  name and anonymity is thereby mostly achieved. Downvoting rather mindlessly might discourage some clearly competent people to participate at this forum and that is a loss to everybody interested in physics.

@BioPhysicist But more broadly, I believe that if downvotes are required to accompany some explanation then it would discourage such mindless downvotes while simultaneously inform others of the "why" and thereby helping both the poster and other readers interested in the matter. I understand that this is not something the moderators can change but they could bring it up to the "operators" of this stack exchange as a potentially useful addition to their product. If they don't like it then they will not do so but as the great social philosopher Lieutenant Callahan said "Opinions are like ..."

@hyportnex I wasn't being hostile, nor was my recent comment discussing anonymity. I was just commenting on the behavior of upvoting something only because it was down voted

@hyportnex the concept of anonymous criticism is hardly limited to our site, as anyone who has submitted a manuscript to a journal can attest.  Taking a page from the peer-review textbook, most referees prefer to stay anonymous because they feel anonymity allows them to state opinions free (or at least freer) from the possibility of retribution.

Admittedly, PSE questions and answers are NOT like submission to a peer-reviewed journal, but there is no reason to believe that the reactions of some people to criticisms would be different, and there is no reason to believe that having named downvotes would have a positive effect any more than a named referee report would.

In fact, I certainly feel that some users would not be as honest in their voting if their votes (upvotes or downvotes) were identified.  In particular, I’m willing to bet that downvotes of high-rep users would probably be less frequent (although I’m not willing to make the experiment).

you are right that constructive comments are important, like constructive peer-reviews are important, but they don’t have to be tied to downvotes in any ways.  I think it’s enough that, on occasions, users who have downvoted a specific question, take time to answer additional queries from the OP.  You can find ample examples of this on this meta.

(I hope this will not add to your annoyance if I tell you I am actually quite annoyed by the massive downvote of this question...)

@ZeroTheHero Thank you for your comments. I am not annoyed by downvotes per se, I am only annoyed, if  that is right word, by downvotes that make no sense to me. The many comments and the below long post were kind of answers, negative on the whole with yours excepted, but answers nevertheless that state positions more or less clearer and not just downvotes. If you look at the link in my post above was really the one that triggered my post originally, especially the downvote against the answer of basics, ....

....and I was not concerned basics might get discouraged writing more on this website but because a downvote like that might confuse a student less versed than the seasoned people in this comment thread hating even my question let alone suggestion. And, finally, the post by basics may be correct or may be incorrect technically but it is a well-written and coherent explication that took time and work on his part to write; it deserved more than a careless and senseless downvote. Again, thank you.

TLDR.  In an ideal world populated by ideal people, public voting would be lovely.  We don't, alas, live in an ideal world and some people don't play nice with other people.  We have to protect the majority (who act reasonably) from the minority (who do not).
Voting has been anonymous on SE simply because if you force people to reveal their identity when they vote, this will inevitably lead to people holding grudges, which they may retaliate due to (and this has happened me).
The reality is that some people seem unable to take any criticism and I've dealt with plenty of people who react to explanations for a downvote I did post as a comment by becoming aggressively combative and refusing to accept any criticism (even when the comment explaining the problem is significantly upvoted by other members).
If you force people to comment when voting, then their identities are going to be visible.  We don't want that because unfortunately some people treat criticism as personal attacks.
Making these comments anonymous would, I think, make the system quite complex and would require an SE/SO wide rewrite of the code underlying the system.  There's also the issue of how to notify the poster of an anonymous comment that someone replied to them, as an anonymous comment won't be able to to used to reply using the "@" mechanism.
Voting is an earned privilege.  You have to gain enough reputation by other actions (and by not misbehaving) to gain this privilege.  It's impossible to create a system that's foolproof, but the theory is that users who earn the privilege will act responsibly.
Also note that, if these downvotes you complain about are the result of a pattern of behavior by one individual then my understanding is that the system has built in detection code for that.  It does, in my experience, take time to kick in (possibly the system raises the issue with a human operator for review).
I've also seen instances in the past where question posters don't like the answers they get (e.g. because they only want their own ideas confirmed even if they're clearly wrong). Some of these people (who are mercifully rare) don't react passively or accept the good faith of other users trying to help them.

Agreed.  Some people take downvotes waaaay too seriously.  Moreover, whereas there are certainly silly downvotes, there are certainly also silly upvotes.  Although not a remedy, one must hope that toxic downvoters eventually get bored and move on.

Some people take votes waaaay too seriously FTFY @ZeroTheHero

@KyleKanos Good point.
